# Selenium Python Microsoft Edge. Open a browser in GUEST PROFILE (not inprivate/incognito)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, profile

I am trying to run my msedge web driver in guest profile, but only I found on the internet were inprivate mode articles...

I tried using the Guest Profile folder:

```
self.options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data\\Guest Profile")
```

But it still opens it just as profile 2 or any other random profile.

Comment: do you have that folder in your c: disk?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created a Guest profile in Microsoft Edge before running the WebDriver.

1. Open Microsoft Edge and click on the profile icon in the top-right corner.
2. Select "Browse as Guest" from the menu.
   Microsoft Edge will open in Guest mode.
3. Close the Microsoft Edge window.
   Navigate to the user data directory and locate the Guest profile folder.

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/161903-how-browse-guest-mode-microsoft-edge-chromium.html

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://www.gridlastic.com/disable-edge-personalize-your-web-experience-prompt.html) on Gridlastic:

> Starting from Edge 114 there is a "Personalize your web experience"
> prompt that randomly activates and might effect your test. This prompt
> can be disabled by passing in the argument **"--guest"**.

This should sort you in Selenium v4:

```
options.add_argument('--guest')
```

Cheers